# Display discount percentage in Magento Category View

Tags: magento, categories, discount

I've been trying to display the discount % for each product in the category listing without having to install an extension.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After searching through several tutorials, I found a way to do it:

1. Open app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml
2. Locate ""
3. Above that line, add:

   ```
   <?php if($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
   <?php $_Percent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price)*100); ?>
       <p class="special-price">
           <span class="price" style="width: 50px; height; 50px; height: 50px;border-radius: 50%; background: red; color: white;position: relative;display: block;float: right;margin-top: -100px;text-align: center;/* padding: 5px; */line-height: 50px; font-weight: 800">ca
               <?php echo $_Percent; ?>%
           </span>
       </p>
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```

That's it. A few suggestions though: 
Instead of modifying base/default files, create your own versions in a subtheme.
Use proper CSS in a stylesheet instead of inline.

Answer (score 0):

- Open :

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

or

> app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

- Locate : `<?php endif; /* if ($_finalPrice == $_price): */ ?>`
- Above that line add:

      `<?php // Display Discount percents start ?>
      <?php if($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
      <?php $_savingPercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price)*100); ?>
          <p class="special-price yoursaving">
              <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Discount:') ?></span>
              <span class="price">
                  <?php echo $_savingPercent; ?>%
              </span>
          </p>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php // Display Discount percent end ?>`